# Can a property of an object described in a TypeScript interface implement the interface itself inside its declaration?

Tags: typescript, types

I know this is probably a strange request, but in my case it would perfectly fit.

I have an object called `layer` which can be something like this:

```
const layer = {
    Title: 'parent title',
    Name: 'parent name',
    Layer: {
        Title: 'child title'
    }
}
```

It has a `Title` property which is mandatory and a `Name` and `Layer` properties which are optional.

In case the `Layer` property is present, it has the same characteristics just described (thus, it could have other nested `Layer`s).

I need to define an *interface* for it, and I thought something like this might work:

```
interface LayerInterface {
    Title: string;
    Name?: string;
    Layer?: LayerInterface;
}
```

My question is whether I can use the `LayerInterface` as the type of `Layer` property which is defined in `LayerInterface` itself.

I am just curios if this can be done this or another simple way.

Comment: Yes, you can create recursive types like this where the recursion happens down in a property

Comment: Great! I could not find any information to confirm this. Should you post this comment as answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I'm still looking for an obvious piece of official-ish documentation that says this works for interfaces.  There's a relevant section for `type` aliases [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases); see the `Tree<T>` type.  Probably this is in the (largely outdated) [spec](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md)...

Comment: You can always open the Typescript playground to try out examples like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your recursive interface definition:

```
interface LayerInterface {
    Title: string;
    Name?: string;
    Layer?: LayerInterface;
}
```

compiles successfully and means what you intend for it to mean:

```
function processLayer(layer: LayerInterface) {}

processLayer(layer); // okay

const badLayer = { Title: "", Name: "", Layer: { Title: 123, Name: false } }
processLayer(badLayer); // error!
// --------> ~~~~~~~~
/* Argument of type
  '{ Title: string; Name: string; Layer: { Title: number; Name: boolean; }; }' 
  is not assignable to parameter of type 'LayerInterface'. 
*/
```

You can see how `badLayer` fails to match `LayerInterface` because of the `Title` and `Name` properties of the nested `Layer` object are the wrong type.

---

Note that this isn't a strange request at all; many commonly used interfaces and classes work this way at least to some extent.  Any tree structure, such as the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), will have a type definition where some of its properties and methods make some reference to the type being defined.

A DOM [`Element`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5251) node has a [`children`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L11559) property representing an [array-like collection of `Element` nodes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L6594), allowing you to write recursive element-processing functions:

```
function processElement(elem: Element) {
    console.log(elem.nodeName);
    for (let i = 0; i < elem.children.length; i++) {
        processElement(elem.children[i]);
    }
}
```

---

As for documentation:

It looks like the "official" documentation saying you can do this for interfaces lives in the (increasingly outdated) [TypeScript Spec](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/136f728bb011ecf1bbf0ff2aac6dacc5cb6568cb/doc/spec.md#3118-recursive-types):

> Classes and interfaces can reference themselves in their internal structure, in effect creating recursive types with infinite nesting. For example, the type
>
> ```
> interface A { next: A; }
> ```
>
> contains an infinitely nested sequence of 'next' properties.

It also works in type aliases, as mentioned in [the handbook section on type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases):

> We can also have a type alias refer to itself in a property:
>
> ```
> type Tree<T> = {
>    value: T;
>    left: Tree<T>;
>    right: Tree<T>;
> }
> ```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDJwJ7QJLmvJZAbwChlzkAVYMAGwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4yKA5OAFsIAfiat2Ibr3LosUMWkw48sRBB4BfEiQQB7EK2S1lUZAF5iMqjXpMA5AAc4UCOGRhbEewBprA4QdnV3cQIW8-CiV5JlIoqOo6RmR7BAALYFoAEw8ve2ttbRIYAFcQBE8DZEcoPSRmZjloAAoTGOiVSDUkAEpiIpq6iAamqFbTHq5kAHpp5D0Aa0wdfUMwZAAjOCzRi2IbJKYAIiOfZADkk7PR2IO7ZABGACYAZjOLpnhaZhRNZG1BvVGqZmlsdhMprNkNBalAAIQkKEAWhRqJRAD5kAA-HG4nGIgBUyAAglAOCVhO49DAPBhHBBePYiHdkhJOFMPiw2OyOlBbol7iAKRtoBzwkwNno9PQ4CAppp5fZkLxgMxkCA9Os4A1gBwwht6B49NUXOEuvMaWA6Sh7KNcF0CN4AHTKgnTHSlcqVEDVWpAgCi9EpYGaECDTEDEGDfTiFFWzGlECdtD0HFDQadGqyEAuk2sMD0ZlaEHWwD2AAYpmWADzQjPpTJZELJtwcMBpKsAak7MesUUBw2YkeD6ajTob2RCAG1gABdPNRQo6ZBAA)

Comment: "Okay, hope that helps" Well, that's more than helpful. Thanks for this thorough explanation, really appreciate it!